# Android custom item adapter for list view

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I want to create an item adapter that will look like this when displaying in the list view:

[image]

The data model I want to use to create this looks like this:

```
TrainingProgram
   - name: String
   - intervals: Array<TrainingInterval>

TrainingInterval
   - intensityType: Enum {WarmUp, Low, Medium, High, CoolDown}
   - durationInSeconds: Int
```

Now the layout I'm thinking of would be like this:

```
RelativeLayout
   - programTitle: TextView - set to top left
   - totalTime: TextView - set to top right
   - colorMap: ImageView - set to bottom and with fill parent horizontally
```

My problem starts when I want to create that color map, with colors being of different width based on the TrainingInterval length in seconds.

How can I create that color map starting from the model described above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The color map ,You can use the LinearLayout.Because The component in LinearLayout has a attribute "layout_weight".Like this:

```
<LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1"
    />
    <ImageView
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can I specify the weight when adding the imageViews dynamically?

Comment: Implemented like this and it works. I will accept your answer. Thanx